# DNN 9.3.0 - search bar not showing files after update

Tags: dotnetnuke

After updating from DNN 9.1 to 9.3, I am unable to find any documents when I'm doing a search in my DNN site. I have tried re-indexing and running the file crawler, site crawler and url crawler multiple times.  I have also attempted at synching my assets for every portal.  Also noted, I have been recycling the app pool and deleting the files in the AppData/Search folder after each failed attemps.  I have noticed that whenever I run a task such as re-indexing or running a task in Scheduler that the AppData/Search folder gets a write.lock file. Is there something I am missing?

Comment: When you search, open up the network console in your browser (press f-12 and click on network) see if it is making any calls. I imagine it is, and there's a 500 error being thrown.

Comment: I'm not too sure what to say, after not trying to fix this issue for a week, the search seems to be working just fine today.  I am unsure why it took so long to work after removing everything in the AppData/Search folder, re-indexing, syncing the assets and running the crawlers.  I checked on the console and network section in DevTools (Chrome) and see no errors.  I'll turn this up as complete, but I will keep an eye out for errors being thrown in the console and network tab, even if I haven't seen any in the past. Thank you @ChrisHammond for your help.  It's always appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After not trying to fix this issue for a week, the search seems to be working just fine today. I am unsure why it took so long to work after removing everything in the AppData/Search folder, re-indexing, syncing the assets and running the crawlers. I checked on the console and network section in DevTools (Chrome) and see no errors. I'll turn this up as complete.